# Errors with linked tables and Ms Access ( Run-time error '3622' : dbSeeChanges/Identity column )

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to output the name of all linked tables, including their fields which are Date/Time, and that fields values.

The following code can output the first table, field name and their first value, not all values, although when it gets to the next linked table, I get this error

```
Run-time Error '3622' 
You must use the dbSeeChanges option with OpenRecordSet when accessing a SQL Server table that has an IDENTITY column.
```

Here is my code

```
Private Sub btnGetFields_Click()

   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Dim f As Field
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim numField As Integer

   Set db = CurrentDb

   For Each tdf In db.TableDefs

        If Left$(tdf.Connect, 9) = "ODBC;DSN=" Then

            Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tdf.Name)
            numField = rst.Fields.Count

            Debug.Print "Table: " & tdf.Name
            For index = 0 To numField - 1
                 If rst.Fields(index).Type = dbDate Then

                     Debug.Print "Field: " & rst.Fields(index).Name; "   Value : "; rst.Fields(index).Value
                 End If
            Next



        End If

   Next

   Set tdf = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

I read something that if I'm using sql tables I should use ADO?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can continue to use your existing DAO code, just change

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tdf.Name)
```

to

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tdf.Name, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

That opens a static read-only Recordset, so `dbSeeChanges` is not required.